# Frame the solution using Dynamic programming

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming

Given a bag with a maximum of 100 chips,each chip has its value written over it.
Determine the most fair division between two persons. This means that the difference between the amount each person obtains should be minimized. The value of a chips varies from 1 to 1000.

Input: The number of coins m, and the value of each coin.

Output: Minimal positive difference between the amount the two persons obtain when they divide the chips from the corresponding bag.

I am finding it difficult to form a DP solution for it. Please help me.

Initially I had to tried it as a Non DP solution.Actually I havent thought of solving it using DP. I simply sorted the value array. And assigned the largest value to one of the person, and incrementally assigned the other values to one of the two depending upon which creates minimum difference. But that solution actually didnt work.

I am posting my solution here :

bool myfunction(int i, int j)

{

```
return(i >= j) ;
```

}

int main()

{

```
int T, m, sum1, sum2, temp_sum1, temp_sum2,i ;

cin >> T ;

while(T--)

    {

        cin >> m ;

        sum1 = 0 ; sum2 = 0 ; temp_sum1 = 0 ; temp_sum2 = 0 ;

        vector<int> arr(m) ;

        for(i=0 ; i < m ; i++)

            {

                cin>>arr[i] ;

            }

            if(m==1 )

                {

                    if(arr[0]%2==0)
                        cout<<0<<endl ;

                    else
                        cout<<1<<endl ;
                }

        else {      

        sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), myfunction) ;

    //  vector<int> s1 ;

    //  vector<int> s2 ;

        for(i=0 ; i < m ; i++)

            {

                temp_sum1 = sum1 + arr[i] ;

                temp_sum2 = sum2 + arr[i] ;

                if(abs(temp_sum1 - sum2) <= abs(temp_sum2 -sum1))

                    {

                        sum1 = sum1 + arr[i] ;
                    }

                    else

                        {

                            sum2 = sum2 + arr[i] ;
                        }

                        temp_sum1 = 0 ;

                        temp_sum2 = 0 ;

            }

            cout<<abs(sum1 -sum2)<<endl ;


      }

    }



return 0 ;
```

}

Comment: Hi @GuillaumeF. Actually I havent thought of solving it using DP. I simply sorted the value array. And assigned the largest value to one of the person, and incrementally assigned the other values to one of the 
two depending upon which creates minimum difference. But that solution actually didnt work. I am posting my solution here :                           .......

Comment: You haven't asked a question yet.

Comment: @RaymondChen So, what is the correct way to approach it??

Comment: "What is the correct way to solve it" is not a specific programming problem. A specific programming question would be "Here is my attempted solution, but it fails when X because Y. How can I stop it from doing Y?" Merely posting your attempted solution without saying what is wrong is not sufficient.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondChen, Yes it worked for me on some test cases like, if the array is 1 2 3 4 5, then it would assign (5,2,1) and (4,3) respectively with diff 1, which is correct. likewise if the array is 1 2 100, it would assign (1,2) and (100) respectively with min diff 97, which is also correct. But if the array is 3 5 5 6 7, then it would assign (6,5,3) and (7,5) with diff 2, while the actual result should be (3,5,5) and (6,7) with diff 0.

Comment: So what is your question? It sounds like the problem is with the algorithm, not the code.

Comment: Yes @RaymondChen, problem is with my approach. It is not the correct algorithm. Thats what I asked how to approach this problem, possibly it is a dynamic programming problem.

Comment: This is a variation of the standard Partition Problem. Other discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065554/algorithms-for-dividing-an-array-into-n-parts).

Answer (score 0):

what i understand from your question is you want to divide chips in two persons so as to minimize the difference between sum of numbers written on those.
If understanding is correct, then potentially you can follow below approach to arrive at solution.

1. Sort the values array i.e. int values[100]
2. Start adding elements from both ends of array in for loop i.e. for(i=0; j=values.length;i<j;i++,j--)
3. Odd numbered iteration sum belongs to one person & even numbered sum to other person
4. run the loop till i < j
5. now, the difference between two sums obtained in odd & even iterations should be minimum as array was sorted earlier.

If my understanding of the question is correct, then this solution should resolve your problem.

Reflect as appropriate.

Thanks

Ravindra

Comment: I don't think your algorithm works in general. Consider [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10].

Comment: in this case, you can create final array to be used for above algorithm by combining repeated values sum in one array element.So, above array becomes [10,10] & applying above algorithm calculates the difference to be 0.

Comment: @RaViMete, I didnt understand your solution. What if the array is 3 5 5 6 7. According to your solution, (3+7) will be assigned to person1, and (5+6) will be assigned to person2. What about the remaining 5 ?? Its actual ans is 0 by assigning  (3,5,5) to one, and (6,7) to other.                                       .                                    I would also like to mention that they need not get same number of coins. One might get only one and the other one might get rest all.

Comment: @RaViMete Combining repeated values won't help with [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,45]